# .play(function (){ }); jquery not working

Tags: jquery, function

I want a function to occur as soon as a play the video. I have the following code but it isn't working.

```
$(".jw-video")[0].play(function (){
  var link = $(".jw-video").attr("src");
  console.log(link);
});
```

Please help.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Why do you think it would work?

Comment: Maybe try:

`$(".jw-video")[0].live('playing', function(){
  var link = $(".jw-video").attr("src");
  console.log(link);
});`

Comment: @sscotti `.live` is obsolete, and has been removed for a while. Plus `[0]` means it's probably not a jQuery object.

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: Are you trying to use the JWPlayer plugin?

Comment: Yes but I have disabled flash so it switches to html 5 video

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara Thanks for that.  I did find something that might work and reposted.

Answer (score 0):

Did a little research.  This seems to work, although there is probably a better way than mixing and matching straight JS and jQuery and it could be cleaned up a bit, but it seems to work.  This is a very helpful link:

[W3 Org Video Media Events](https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)

JS / jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function() {
videoElement = $(".jw-video")[0];
videoElement.addEventListener("playing", playHandler, false);
function playHandler(e) {
    alert("playing");
  var link = $(".jw-video")[0].currentSrc;
  console.log(link);
}
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<video class="jw-video" width="320" height="240" controls>
<source id="mp4" src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Not sure why $(".jw-video")[0].controller returns null ?  Not in the code, but I wanted to see how that works.